# if else acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, acrobat

Could someone please advise where I can get assistance with the following script.
I am using the trigger of mouse exit within the 'action' tab.
I would ideally like the script to run, as soon as the user types the first character into the Desc field (ie IF statement), and then again upon exit from this field to check if user has subsequently deleted the characters and left the field blank (ie ELSE statement).
If the field is clicked and nothing type, the script should run the 'else' portion, thus leaving the associated fields at their default values and properties.

Starting with the fields set by default as 'read only' the following script changes the fields to accessible and sets the rfields as required after exiting the Desc field.
However, if the desc field is blanked again, the else statement does not run

```
// validate the Description field
// create a variable for the xxR fields - field name hierarchy
// create a variable for the xxO fields - field name hierarchy

var desc = this.getField("A1Desc"); 
var rfields = this.getField("A1R");
var ofields = this.getField("A1O");

if (this.getField(desc)!="")
     {
     rfields.readonly = false;
     rfields.required = true;
     ofields.readonly = false;
     }
else 
     {
     rfields.required = false;
     rfields.value = rfields.defaultValue;
     ofields.value = ofields.defaultValue;
     rfields.readonly = true;
     ofields.readonly = true;
     }
```

Comment: We would need to see your trigger code rather than just this code.

Comment: Sorry - I am just setting the field properties in Acrobat field properties, action tab to perform an action based on mouse up / mouse dwn/ mouse enter / mouse exit / mouse focus or mouse blur, and then run this javascript. None of these have enabled me to get the 'else' script to run. I am new to this so any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: output `this.getField(desc)` when you think else should run, it may not be the value you think it is.  if it is a ' ' it will look blank but won't run your code

Comment: changing the IF statement to: if (!event.willCommit && event.value != "")  has fixed the current problem